# Can not connect Docker Daemon from Rasher Desktop to IntelliJ IDEA (Mac OS)

Tags: docker, configuration

I recently changed Docker Desktop to the Rasher Desktop and **I want to connect Docker Daemon to IntelliJ IDEA**.

There are two options avaliable to setup connection: default docker and tcp connection.

By default it's serching for docker.sock at `/var/run/docker.sock` dir but in my case docker.sock is placed at `/Users/<USER>/.rd/docker.sock`

I tried to create tcp connection from docker deamon but without any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution and it does not require to change docker.sock path anywhere.

I created a link to the new file and it worked to connect docker.sock using the default docker configuration

```
sudo ln -svf /Users/${USER}/.rd/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

[image: docker_config]